# manage.py and docker-compose in different directories?

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I am no expert with docker and what I want to do I think should not be hard, I simply want to be able to run manage.py commands having my docker-compose in different directory and NOT specifying the location of manage.py when I'm running the command.

So right now I have a directory that has a the docker-compose.yml and a folder called backend where the manage.py file is. I just want to be able to run

```
docker-compose run --rm web python3 manage.py
```

instead of

```
docker-compose run --rm web python3 backend/manage.py
```

How can I do it?

This is my compose file

```
version: '3'

services: 
    db:
        image: postgres:13
        env_file: .env
    
    web:
        build: 
            context: ./backend
        env_file: .env
        command: python backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on: 
            - db
```

Comment: Mount the backend directory to the working directory of the container via the volumes config for the service. The working directory is where your command will be run from

Comment: can you include your docker-compose.yml file so that I can provide a specific solution?

Comment: There it is the compose file @maxm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem.
One of them is setting the `working_dir` instead of mounting the directory to a different directory:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    db:
        image: postgres:13
        env_file: .env
    
    web:
        build: 
            context: ./backend
        env_file: .env
        working_dir: /code/backend
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on: 
            - db
```

setting the working directory is equivalent to changing the current working directory to the given directory, i.e. 'cd' into it.
Every further command which includes the python3 manage.py command is then executed with the directory set as its current directory.

Notice how the `command`-line changes in the docker-compose file